# Postgres Date and ID fill in Zero if no entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table that has the following format:

purchase_time | user_id | items_purchased

The current query I'm doing is something like this:

```
SELECT user_id, date(purchase_time), sum(items_purchased)
from user_purchase_metrics
GROUP BY date(purchase_time), user_id;
```

I'm trying to create a query that will fill in 0 for purchases if there isn't an entry in that date for that given user. Is this possible?

Comment: Outer join a calendar table/cte.

Comment: FYI, `timestamp` is a [Reserved/Key word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) I would avoid using it for field name. I'm not seeing anything in the query output that refers to `clicks`. What are you defining as clicks?

Comment: Yes/No.  A query can only return data existing data.  Thus a query can't return a day not in the system.  You either need to have a table listing all days and outer join to it as suggested; dynamically generate all days between a range your looking for {*shudder*} not optimal performance wise and not really re-usable and out join to it or generate the missing dates outside the result set in the application you're presenting the data in.

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistencies in the example. I'm trying to take a work issue and redact it for a simple question. It should be resolved now.

Comment: What is your desired range of dates?  The max and min of date(purchase_time), some fixed range, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Side stepping the valid concern by @xQbert about generating missing dates performance must always give way to necessity. Without a convenient calendar table generating the dates of interest is a necessity. Moreover, in this case the dates must be generated for each user_id. In the following this is done by generating each date with the distinct user_id from the `user_purchase_metrics` table. The result is then LEFT joined to the same table to sum the purchases and giving the desired 0 results for the missing dates. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1020f1b68934c872c96356d5de7d215c), for dates I just picked March):

```
with dates( user_id, idate ) as 
     ( select user_id, d::date
        from ( select distinct  user_id 
                from user_purchase_metrics
             ) u 
         join generate_series( date '2021-03-01'       --- start_date 
                             , date '2021-03-31'       --- end_date 
                             , interval '1 day'
                             ) gs(d)
           on true      
      )  -- select * from dates; 
select d.user_id
     , d.idate 
     , coalesce(sum(pm.items_purchased),0)   
  from dates d 
  left join user_purchase_metrics pm
         on (    pm.user_id = d.user_id 
             and date(pm.purchase_time) = d.idate
            ) 
 group by d.user_id, d.idate
 order by d.user_id, d.idate;
```

To parametrize the query can be embedded in a SQL function that returns a table. (Also in demo).